# C# Two Forms accessing the same class data

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using MS Visual C# 2010.

I created 2 WPF forms, MainWindow.xaml and CreateCharacter.xaml. I did Project->Add Class... to add an empty class called Hero.cs. The Hero class will hold the players name and other vital data.

In the MainWindow.xaml.cs I made an instance of the Hero class: `Hero player = new Hero();`. I click a button on the MainWindow and it opens the CreateCharacter form. On the CreateCharacter form I want to enter the players name and store this data in player.name, which was instantiated in MainWindow.

How do I make the Hero object I created in the MainWindow class available to the CreateCharacter class?

Answer (score 3):

If the CreateCharacter form is creating a character, then perhaps it should create the Hero instance. It could return it in a public property that the main form could read after the CreateCharacter form successfully returned.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably one of the most common questions ever asked on internet forums.
I suggest you get familiar with object-oriented programming before diving into GUI programming so you understand the basic concepts.

To pass an object to another window, you could add a special constructor that accepts it as a parameter, and a property or field to hold it (depending on whether you want to make it accessible or not):

```
partial class CreateCharacterWindow : Window {
    private Character character;

    public CreateCharacterWindow ()
        : this (null) { } // designer requires parameterless constructor

    public CreateCharacterWindow (Character character)
    {
        this.character = character;
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
}

var spiderman = new Character ();
var charWindow = new CreateCharacterWindow (spiderman);
```

**I happen to dislike this approach though.**

It seems logical that you intend to *create* the character in the very window you're about to show. What is the point of creating the object before the window is shown? **I believe it's `CreateCharacterWindow`'s reponsibility to actually instantiate `Character` because it knows most about its properties**, and anyway there is no sense in having dummy character before user presses **Create** button or something similar if you don't plan to use databinding.

If you do intend to use databinding, create a public readonly `Character` property in `CreateCharacterWindow` so `MainWindow` could access it, instantiate it in the constructor, assign the instance to `DataContext` object and wire up UI controls and object properties in XAML markup.

**But I wouldn't use databinding in this case either.**

What I would do is to show `CreateCharacterWindow` modally with `ShowModal` method. In this class I would set `this.DialogResult` to `true` if the user chooses to actually create the character (as opposed to pressing Cancel button, for example).

`ShowModal` will return value we assigned to `DialogResult` so `MainWindow` knows if the user really wants to create the character. If this is the case, we finally ask `CreateCharacterWindow` to create `Character` instance:

```
partial class CreateCharacterWindow : Window {

    public CreateCharacterWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        createButton.Click += (sender, e) => {
            this.DialogResult = true;
            this.Close ();
        };
    }

    public Character CreateCharacter ()
    {
        return new Character {
            Name = nameBox.Text
        };
    }
}

var createWindow = new CreateCharacterWindow ();
var doCreate = createWindow.ShowDialog ();

if (doCreate ?? false) { // if DialogResult was not specified, assume it's false 
    var character = createWindow.CreateCharacter ();
    // do whatever you like with it
}
```

This method lacks some WPF databinding fanciness but I like that `Character` only gets created when there indeed *is* a character from business logic point of view, and the object doesn't act like some placeholder that may or may not be used.

Answer (score 0):

add to your CreateCharacter argument or property of Hero class, and pass it to its constructor or any else method.

Comment: @Kirk, are we talking about creating multiple constructors?

Comment: @Snowbear - I don't know, that would depend how tightly coupled these two classes are / should be.  I just don't understand why passing a reference to a constructor is 'wrong'.

Comment: @Kirk, I believe creating non-default ctor for Controls is wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common pattern.  Here's how I'd do it in WPF.

In the view model for the main window, there should be a property called `Characters` that's an `ObservableCollection<CharacterViewModel>`.  In the view, this is bound to some kind of items control, say a `ListBox`.  There's either a `DataTemplate` for the `CharacterViewModel`, or the class implements `ToString()`, so that the characters are presented usefully.  The `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` is bound to a `SelectedCharacter` property in the view model, so that whenever the user clicks on an item in the list box, the view model knows what the currently-selected character is.

The main window view model also implements an `EditingCharacter` event (it's just an ordinary event handler) and an `EditCharacterCommand` (using [Josh Smith's `RelayCommand` pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)), and its accompanying property and method, e.g.:

```
public bool CanEditCharacter { get { return SelectedCharacter != null; } }

public void EditCharacter()
{
   EventHandler h = EditingCharacter;
   if (EditingCharacter != null)
   {
      EditingCharacter(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}
```

The `EditCharacterCommand` is bound to a clickable control (a button or hyperlink, say) in the view.

The main window *view* instantiates the main window view model and registers a handler for the `EditingCharacter` event:

```
private void ViewModel_EditingCharacter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CharacterViewModel cvm = ((MainWindowViewModel)sender).SelectedCharacter;
   CharacterWindow cw = new CharacterWindow();
   cw.ShowDialog(cvm);
}
```

(Why use an event?  Because using events keeps the implementation details of creating and displaying windows outside of the view model objects.  The `CharacterViewModel` doesn't need to know any details about how characters are edited.  It just raises an event saying "hey, it's time to edit the currently-selected character."  It's up to the main window to decide what it's going to do when the event is raised.)

The `CharacterWindow` is what actually lets the user edit a character.  Its controls are bound to properties of the `CharacterViewModel`.  It implements an overload of `ShowDialog`:

```
public bool? ShowDialog(CharacterViewModel cvm)
{
   DataContext = cvm;
   return ShowDialog();
}
```

(Making it possible to cancel this dialog without saving changes is an exercise for the reader.)

Finally, you *also* implement an `AddCharacterCommand` in the window view model - it creates a new `CharacterViewModel`, adds it to the `Characters` collection, sets `SelectedCharacter`, and raises `EditingCharacter`.  Bind this to a button or hyperlink or menu item in the main window, and you're done.